# How do I seamlessly replace a hard disk?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have 2 drives on my PC (Win10):

- C:\ - SSD for the OS
- D:\ - HDD for everything else

D:\ has a lot of software/files/games installed on it.  It is currently dying but still functional.
Additionally, I changed some settings when first receiving the PC to have D:\ as the default location - e.g. Desktop, AppData etc. though I'm not sure how I did this specifically.

I purchased a new HDD, and I want to transfer everything from D:\ to the new drive, remove D:\ drive, and 'rename' the new drive to be D:\  It that possible?  or is there a better way to accomplish this?

I also have a HDD docking station, so I can have both drives connected at the same time.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qo8ZIbW.png This is how you changed the location of those folders

Comment: What size are the sSD and HDD?

Comment: @davidgo SSD is 250gb (92gb free),  old HDD is 2T,  new HHD is 4T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 options.

**1 If you are not afraid of Linux...**

By far the easiest method for your case would be to connect the new HDD as a 3rd drive and then boot from a Linux live USB.
From within Linux make a 1 on 1 partition copy from the old HDD to the new one. (The new one needs to be same size or bigger obviously.)
After the copy is completed shut down the system. Replace the old HDD with the new one and boot into Windows.
With a little luck Windows won't know the difference. There is a small chance the new HDD isn't D but gets a different drive-letter. If that happens ignore all error messages (if any) and go straight into Disk Administrator and change the drive-letter to D. Then immediately reboot.

That is all. If the new HDD is bigger you probably want to go back the Disk Administrator and expand the D: volume into the extra space at the end of the disk.

**2 If the partition copy failed (because disk is already going bad) or if you can't handle Linux.**

Connect he new HDD as 3rd drive. Make a new volume on the disk (E:) and format that as NTFS using Disk Administrator.
Now create the folderstructure on E: and copy (don't move!) to the new disk all those folders you had re-directed from C:.
DO NOT use the config settings that Gantendo linked to in the comments above and which I have inserted below as well. In this case the drive-letter is temporary so you don't want Windows to update its registry with the new location settings.
(File Explorer is not really good for this. I strongly recommend you use an alternative file-manager like e.g. TotalCommander, DirOpus or Alltap Salamander for this that will give you no grief about hidden files. File Explorer also doesn't always show you what is really happening on disk and in this case you don't need that. It is really important you make an exact copy of those folders.)

Shutdown the computer, replace the HDD and start up. (Don't connect the old HDD!). New HDD is still called E:. Use Disk Administrator to change that to D: and reboot.
Now you can connect the old drive as external disk (it probably gets called E: now) and  copy over everything else you still need from the old drive.

**3 If all that sounds way to complicated and you don't mind the new disk being called E: afterwards**

Connect the new HDD as external drive. Format it using Disk Administrator. It will get the drive letter E:
For those folders (like Documents) that where redirected to D: go to the Properties of those folders and use the Move button to move them to E:.
[image: Move Documents location]
That may take a while. If you get read errors (disk is going bad after all) ignore those and continue.
Then copy everything else from D: to E:.
Last step is to shutdown the computer and replace the old HDD with the new one. Windows should now boot up with an E: drive and no D: drive.

You may run into some applications that still look for D: which is now gone.  There is a trick for that: Open a Command Prompt or Powershell with "Run as Administrator" and give the command `SUBST D: E:`. This will create a 2nd virtual drive-letter D: referring to the E: drive.
You only need to do this one. It will persist when rebooting. You may have to do that again though after a Windows upgrade to a new version. SUBST assignments sometimes get lost during Windows upgrades.

Comment: Thank you!  I had to opt for option #2 as the disk was already corrupt in places. worked like a charm though :)

Comment: @Shtut Glad to be able to help.